# Highchart - Column chart not coming proper in export api as image

Tags: highcharts

I am getting image from highchart server to add into my pdf. But when I eport an column chart the column bars are coming at below the x-axis and not on the axis itself. Below is demo url
https://jsfiddle.net/ztcv2rhj/6/

```
Highcharts.chart('column-container-print',{
        chart: {  
            animation: false,
            type: "column",
            marginLeft: 80
        }, 
        credits:false,
        title:{
            text: "Top 5 Questions"
        },
        subtitle: false,
        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            min: 0,
        } ,
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ["Are the characters clear and readable? Keyboards should be kept clean. If characters still can't be read, the keyboard may need modifying or replacing. Use a keyboard with a matt finish to reduce glare and/or reflection.","Does the keyboard tilt? Note, the tilt need not be built in.","Does the user have good keyboard technique?","Is it possible to find a comfortable keying position? Try pushing the display screen further back to create more room for the keyboard, hands and wrists. Users of thick raised keyboards may need a wrist rest.","Is the keyboard separate from the screen?"],
            labels: {
                rotation: -45
            }, 
        },
        series: [{"name":"No","data":[1,1,1,1,1]}]
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue occurs because you are providing `chart.options` as options to export. Instead, you should provide `chart.userOptions`.

**Code:**

```
var optionsStr = JSON.stringify(chart.userOptions);
var dataString = encodeURI('async=true&type=jpeg&scale=4&options=' + optionsStr);
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6mw03r7c/

Comment: It worked but caused another issue. x-axis updates on run time via jquery but not reflect in userOptions
    columnChartPrint.xAxis[0].setCategories(categoriesArr);

Comment: Could you send me an example with it? Have you tried to merge a userOptions with a new set of the x-axis?